# How can I add events to a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the following code:
Why aren't my ondrop, ondragover, and onclick functions working? By not working I mean that they are supposed to allow drag and drop of photos from another part of my application.

```
function mattes_draw_letter(x, y, width, height, letter, position) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.style.top = 0 + "px";
    canvas.id = "opening_" + position;
    canvas.ondrop = function (event) {
        drop(event, this);
    };
    canvas.ondragover = function (event) {
        allowDrop(event);
    };
    canvas.onclick = function (event) {
        photos_add_selected_fid(this);
    };
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#bfbfbf';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + letter[0] * width, y + letter[1] * height);
    for (i = 0; i < letter.length; i += 2) {
        if (typeof letter[i + 3] !== 'undefined') {
            ctx.lineTo(x + letter[i + 2] * width, y + letter[i + 3] * height);
        }
    }
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    $("#mattes").append(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Well for one thing, you use "event" in the handler functions but you declare the functions with "e" as the formal parameter. Otherwise, it's hard to say, because nobody knows exactly what you mean when you say they're "not working".

Comment: I changed e to event and explained what I meant by not working. Am I declaring the functions incorrectly or something?

Comment: Do you get errors in the console? Have you verified that the event handler functions are being called?

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: @Pointy - I do not get errors in the console. The events are not being called... that's my issue.

Comment: When I try your code, the events *do* get called. What makes you think that they are not? Have you put `console.log()` calls in the event handlers to verify?

Comment: @AllisonC, you have `canvas.ondrop = function(e)` as the event handler, but the actual function calls pass `event` as a param.  What happens when you replace `event` with `e`?  Also, consider putting a `console.log()` logging statement within the events themselves before calling `drop()` and `allowDrop()`

Comment: @Jason - I changed e to event

Comment: [Here is my jsbin with your code.](http://jsbin.com/eZAHeTID/1) One thing that's curious is that you're using jQuery, but you're using old-fashioned "onfoo" event handler assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to:

```
...
$("#mattes").append(canvas);
canvas.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {drop(event, this);}, false); 
canvas.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {allowDrop(event);}, false); 
canvas.addEventListener("click", function() {photos_add_selected_fid(this);}, false);
```